# MySQL database structure (assign multiple values in one column)?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table that contains a list of words. Each of the words has multiple categories assigned to them. What is the best way to do that?

I do not want to use a set, because the list of categories keeps changing.

I was thinking of having another table that assigns IDs to the categories and then add a field with the list of categories to the table containing the words. Is storing a list of IDs in a text field the "proper" way to do this?

Comment: Please post something you have tried so as the question is better understood.

Comment: Can't your IDs use an integer field?

Answer (score 2):

You create a table that maps words to categories.

Two columns in the table: categoryID, wordID

Answer (score 2):

You should have three table for this:

1. word_table (you already have )- word_id, word, ...
2. categories_table - cat_id, cat_name, ...
3. word_cat_table - cat_id, word_id

here word_id in word_table and cat_id in categories_table is primary key

Comment: Is it possible to link the first and third table so that everytime a word is added to table 1 its ID is automatically added to table 3?

Comment: @eevaa: Impossible. How do you tell to which category it would be added then?
Biswajit: Please, mark the primary keys... it is essential to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Biswajit on creating three tables.

word_table (you already have )- word_id, word,...
    categories_table - cat_id, cat_name, ...
    word_cat_table - cat_id, word_id

The relationship between first and third table could be 1-Many as one work can be in multipe categories.

Comment: Actually, instead of `could be` I'd say `must be` in order to transform the many to many conceptual relationship into the physical level.